# Getting Exception while running the project on Staging(localhost)

Tags: .net-core, architecture

I am trying to run the program but show me exception showing below. I follow the steps that I saw on Stackoverflow , ChatGPT and other websites apply on this but could not get the solution.

[image: Exception 1/3]

[image: Exception 2/3]

[image: Exception 3/3]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution of these exception. These exceptions are occur due to the local Sql Server Database Error. I changed the server name in connection string. Then it doesn't show exception and run properly. Then I uninstall the Sql Server and install again and add the server name in the connection string. After these changes these exception has gone now my project working properly.
Hope this will help in the future if this error occurs.